# Independence Number of Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $\alpha(G)\leq\alpha(H)$ where $G$ and $H$ are graphs, and $\alpha(.)$ is the independence number of graph. Is the following statement true?

$\alpha(G\boxtimes G) \leq \alpha(H\boxtimes H)$ where $\boxtimes$ is the strong product of two graphs.

Answer (score 7):

This is false.

Let $G$ be with edges $ [(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 5), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 5), (4, 5)] $

and $H$ with edges $[(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]  $.

$\alpha(G)=\alpha(H)=2$.

$\alpha(G\boxtimes G)=5,\alpha(H\boxtimes H)=4$.

Comment: Is there any example in which $\alpha(G)<\alpha(H)$ but $\alpha(G\boxtimes G)\geq\alpha(H\boxtimes H)$?

Comment: @MohammadMahdi haven't found any so far...

Answer (score 6):

Surely no. Instead of specific example, let me give general speculations. If this were true, then $\alpha(G)=\alpha(H)$ would imply $\alpha(G\boxtimes G)=\alpha(H\boxtimes H)$, and hence for all strong powers, making Shannon capacity the function of independence number. But SC does not depend only on independence number.

Comment: Are there graph classes where equality for powers hold?

Comment: @joro: Perfect graphs.